# Boot repair doesn't help me. What I should do?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

This is the link gived to me by Boot-Repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11835577/

I can't enter to my ubuntu, When I try it it puts this: `Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.`

These is my history: I had 2 partitions with 2 Ubuntu because in 1 (the first I create) I remove the EFI partition, to fix it I recreate them (obviously with a different UUID). I didn't know that the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file need to have the correct EFI partition's UUID, so when I find out these I edit the file and correct it, but a update which was being carried out was interrupted by the editing of the file. Since then I was trying to repair it.

Sorry for my bad English, it isn't my native language.

Comment: Have you tried running ubuntu from a live usb stick? Then perhaps you can access the grub.cfg and make the proper changes.

Comment: Your English wasn't them problem, the formatting was noisy and pointless. Consider that this doesn't make you stand out from the crowd, it just scares the people off who may be smart enough to solve your problem, but also smart enough to avoid noisy users.

Answer (score 0):

First, the log file indicates that Boot Repair has completed, but your question alludes to manually editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and it's not clear if you did this before or after running Boot Repair. If after, please run Boot Repair again but do *not* edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` manually.

If the system is dropping to a `grub>` prompt as you describe after you run Boot Repair, then that tool is obviously not up for the job. Your Boot Repair seems reasonable, although it's not showing a `grub.cfg` file on your hard disk, which it normally does. Thus, you may want to try a different approach:

1. Disable Secure Boot in your firmware, if it's currently enabled.
2. Download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Prepare a boot medium from the files you download.
4. Boot the rEFInd boot medium. It should show you at least one option to boot Ubuntu.
5. Try the Ubuntu option(s) in rEFInd. If one fails and there's more than one, try the other(s).
6. If you can get into Ubuntu from rEFInd, you have two options:

   - You can install the Debian package or PPA of rEFInd, which will then take over you boot manager duties and get you booting without GRUB.
   - You can attempt to re-install and repair GRUB from your working Ubuntu installation. Given that Boot Repair has already failed at this task, I'm not sure what to suggest, except perhaps `sudo grub-install` followed by `sudo update-grub`.
7. If desired, you can re-enable Secure Boot at this point.

The point of this procedure is simply that rEFInd is not GRUB, and therefore whatever is going wrong with GRUB will not affect rEFInd -- at least, not if the problem is GRUB-specific. It's conceivable that there's something more wrong with your installation. For instance, if you no longer have Linux kernels in `/boot`, you'll have to re-install your kernel packages using an emergency system.